# Generating CHM help and PDF manual from the same source

Tags: documentation, pdf-generation

We are trying to find a set of tools to generate context-sensitive help files (CHM) and manuals (CHM and PDF) from the same sources.
Features wanted are:

- able to deal with ***linked hypertext***
- must be able to generate ***CHM*** and ***PDF*** from
- should be able to integrate ***documentation generated from code*** (currently XML comments)
- ***cross-file*** links would be great
- source format being ***plain text*** (SCM diff-able) would be truly glorious

I suppose that just about every software shop must have run into this problem.
How do you do this?
What tools do you use?
What's your experience with those?

***Edit:*** I thought every shop providing Windows software would have to solve this and many of you would have input for this. It seems I was wrong. although I still wonder how you all do this.
Anyway, thanks for the input of those who answered. We haven't decided yet, but this bounty runs out in a few hours. Unless someone comes in with a glorious suggestion, since the answer suggesting docbook got the most up-votes, I'll pick that one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you considered [DocBook](http://www.docbook.org/)? You can render that as just about anything. See this [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winhelp/docbook_howto.aspx) for examples for CHM generation.

Comment: No, so far we haven't looked at DocBook. We will do now, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Help And Manual http://helpandmanual.com/products_hm_features.html

Answer (score 2):

I love this product

http://www.helpndoc.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve what you want if you implement the following:

1) Generate Html from XML

2) Generate CHM from Html

You can use Microsoft Html Help workshop to generate CHM files using Html, see: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=00535334-c8a6-452f-9aa0-d597d16580cc&displaylang=en

3) Generate PDF from Html using an Html-to-PDF tool.

Comment: I'm afraid that PDF generated from HTML might be hard to layout nicely. The same goes for the other direction. That's why we were looking for a format from which to generate both of them.